# How to start react native app in debug mode without selecting debug js remotely in developer menu

Tags: react-native

I want to have the react native app be connected to the debugger **as** it's being launched. I don't want to have to go in and select "debug js remotely" because by the time I do that the app is already loaded and I can't debug what's going on as it loads.  Also I have redux persist so simply reloading the app after enabling debug won't work because data has already loaded and persisted which alters subsequent reloads.

I'm doing this on an ios simulator. I'm not using expo.

Comment: are you testing on emulator or on your actual phone? are you using expo?

Comment: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you closed the app in debug mode, it will be in debug mode from the start next time you open it.

Comment: Thanks! What about after reinstall?